# Using python requests and beautiful soup to pull text

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

thanks for taking a look at my problem. i would like to know if there is any way to pull the data-sitekey from this text... here is the url to the page https://e-com.secure.force.com/adidasUSContact/

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfI8hoTAAAAAMax5_MTl3N-5bDxVNdQ6Gx6BcKX" data-type="image" id="ncaptchaRecaptchaId"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LfI8hoTAAAAAMax5_MTl3N-5bDxVNdQ6Gx6BcKX&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9lLWNvbS5zZWN1cmUuZm9yY2UuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=en&amp;type=image&amp;v=r20160921114513&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=ei2ddcb6rl03" title="recaptcha widget" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="undefined"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></t
```

here is my current code

```
    import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Host' : 'e-com.secure.force.com',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
}
url = 'https://e-com.secure.force.com/adidasUSContact/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
c = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "data-sitekey"})
print c
```

Answer (score 14):

Ok now we have code, it is as simple as:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://e-com.secure.force.com/adidasUSContact/").content, "html.parser")

key = soup.select_one("#ncaptchaRecaptchaId")["data-sitekey"]
```

*data-sitekey* is an *attribute*, **not** a *css* class so you just need to extract it from the element, you can find the element by it's *id* as above.

You could also use the class name:

```
# css selector
key = soup.select_one("div.g-recaptcha")["data-sitekey"]
# regular find using class name
key = soup.find("div",class_="g-recaptcha")["data-sitekey"]
```

Comment: hey man, curious why do i get none type when i try to get value.....<input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="94ae9386-b3ab-4bc3-bb2d-234e850a0872">