# Web Scraping using BeautifulSoup [alt] [python]

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I am given a HTML code, a part which particularly interests me looks like this:

```
<a href="/go/wydarzenia/rozrywka/35826-majowka-w-twierdzy-klodzko? 
termin=265036" class="link with-img"> <img 
src="/go/resources/main/img//download/img- 
14ab4e372df7bd0826c90f429f0e5933/twierdza-przewodnik-jpg.jpg" alt="Majówka w 
Twierdzy Kłodzko" class=""/>
```

I know that it looks a bit messy but I have to deal with it anyhow.
My job is to extract the text after **alt**.
So in the code above the output should look like this

```
>> Majówka w Twierdzy Kłodzko
```

I read [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) a lot of useful information about extracting data by searching CSS classes or HTML tags. However I didn't find anything anout **alt**.
I would appreciate any help.

---

**Here's my code after some changes**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.wroclaw.pl/go/wydarzenia/rozrywka/eventy'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
print(soup.a.img.attrs["alt"])
```

And the output says that:
*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'*
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute key to get the required value.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<a href="/go/wydarzenia/rozrywka/35826-majowka-w-twierdzy-klodzko? 
termin=265036" class="link with-img"> <img 
src="/go/resources/main/img//download/img- 
14ab4e372df7bd0826c90f429f0e5933/twierdza-przewodnik-jpg.jpg" alt="Majówka w 
Twierdzy Kłodzko" class=""/>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.a.img["alt"])    #or print(soup.a.img.attrs["alt"])
```

**Output:**

```
Majówka w Twierdzy Kłodzko
```

Comment: Thank you! It truerly works. I know that it's not the topic but I need to download the whole page not only our part $s$. What is the best way to do it? Using **urllib3**?

Comment: You are welcome :). You can use `urllib3` or `requests` modules

Comment: Ok. Thanks again! I don't know if I understand it - so **BeautifulSoup** needs a string, doesn't it?

Comment: This link should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757805/using-python-requests-and-beautiful-soup-to-pull-text    They use `requests` with `beautifulsoup`

Comment: Thanks. It did help, however my code still does not work. I would appreciate your looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = '<a href="/go/wydarzenia/rozrywka/35826-majowka-w-twierdzy-klodzko? termin=265036" class="link with-img"> <img src="/go/resources/main/img//download/img- 14ab4e372df7bd0826c90f429f0e5933/twierdza-przewodnik-jpg.jpg" alt="Majówka w Twierdzy Kłodzko" class=""/>'
alt = soup(s, 'lxml').find('img')['alt']
```

Output:

```
u'Maj\xf3wka w Twierdzy K\u0142odzko'
```