# Scraping JavaScript page with python requests and asyncio in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio

**This is far from duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757805/using-python-requests-and-beautiful-soup-to-pull-text) question** since that question doesn't even use requests for scraping but only for session and getting page content. I use it as well in such manner with Beautiful Soup.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python). But they also didn't explain how to use requests effectively for getting JavaScript content.

I'm trying to scrape info from web page which is rendered by JavaScript code. I'm using `requests` module in Jupyter notebook which.

When I use following sample code:

```
import asyncio
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

r = await asession.get('http://python-requests.org')
r.html.render()
r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']
```

I get error:

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

I need some advice on how to implement this [comment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-381440076) to make it work since when I type in Jupyter notebook :

```
asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

I get:

> <_WindowsSelectorEventLoop **running=True** closed=False debug=False>

so I need way to use existing loop in Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python requests and beautiful soup to pull text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757805/using-python-requests-and-beautiful-soup-to-pull-text)

Comment: @simkus it's definitely not.

Comment: @Andrew Svetlov can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much familiar with asyncio but I belive you are supposed to await your function if you are using **AsyncHTMLSession**

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()

async def get_results():
    r = await asession.get('http://python-requests.org')
    return r

a = asession.run(get_results)
print(a[0].html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')) # return None because text is not present there
```

without AsyncHTMLSession

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://python-requests.org')

r.html.render()

print(r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')) # None
```

Comment: Thank you, see update on my question. Do you know how can I use existing async loop in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Harvey hi, do you mean like accessing a current running process in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, see this comment : https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3397#issuecomment-381440076