# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: python, python-requests, pytube

I am trying to program a script that downloads songs from YouTube, but when I want to get first result of the YouTube search I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'html
```

How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import requests
from pytube import YouTube

# Check if a file name and a folder name were provided as command-line arguments
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python download_songs.py <file name> <folder name>")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get the file and folder names from the command-line arguments
file_name = sys.argv[1]
folder_name = sys.argv[2]

# Create the specified folder to save the downloaded songs
if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
    os.makedirs(folder_name)# Prompt the user for the folder name
    

# Read the list of song titles from the input file
with open(file_name) as f:
    song_titles = [line.strip() for line in f]
# Download each song from YouTube and save it to the specified folder
for song_title in song_titles:
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + song_title + "extended mix"
    
# Send the request and get the response
    response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the response and extract the first result
    first_result = response.html.find("h3")[0]
   
# Get the link for the first result
    link = first_result.a["href"]

# Use pytube to download the video at the link
    yt = YouTube(link)
    video = yt.streams.first()
    video.download(folder_name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python requests and beautiful soup to pull text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757805/using-python-requests-and-beautiful-soup-to-pull-text)

Comment: response objects have no html parser or something. See their [attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_response.asp). Best thing you get is the html as text which you can post process by BeautifulSoup for example.

Comment: So you just assumed that there would be an `html` attribute? Did you read `requests` docs?

Answer (score 0):

The line `first_result = response.html.find("h3")[0]` is the problem. The response variable contains an object called Response which has certain attributes but does not contain a `html` attribute. So when you call `response.html` you will get an AttributeError.

Standard, the Response object has the following attributes (which can be found by using `dir(response)`:

`['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text', 'url']`

Now the thing you might be looking for is `response.content` which will give you the html page in string.

However, to get all `h3` elements you will not succeed with only `requests`. You will need another tool, something like: `bs4` also know as `BeautifulSoup` which is a parser that is able to extract all html elements and it's content.

I think the solution that you are looking for is to get all H3 elements, this solution can also be found in this article: [Scraping text in h3 and div tags using beautifulSoup, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933679/scraping-text-in-h3-and-div-tags-using-beautifulsoup-python)

So for your issue: first, at the top add of your script: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Then, if you replace:

```
# Parse the response and extract the first result
    first_result = response.html.find("h3")[0]
```

With:

```
# Parse the response and extract the first result
    content = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    first_result = soup.find_all("h3")[0]
```

You should have the first `h3` element and can get the `"href"` tag from it. Then rest of your script should also work correctly now.